# Proyecto PHP con Jasper Report

Tags: php, jasper-reports

Procedo a aclarar el requerimiento... tengo instalado NetBeans IDE 8.2 al cual instale iReport-5.6.0-plugin en donde he podido realizar algunos reportes que funcionan correctamente, pero al llamarlos desde mi proyecto php solo obtengo una pagina en blanco sin ningun tipo de error. En php he incluido la libreria phpjasperxml_0.9d en donde llamo a mis reportes de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$desde = date("d-m-y", strtotime($_REQUEST['desde'])); 
$hasta = date("d-m-y", strtotime($_REQUEST['hasta']));
//$PHPJasperXML->debugsql=true;
$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("id"=>$_REQUEST['id'],"desde"=>$desde,"hasta"=>$hasta);
$PHPJasperXML->load_xml_file("polizas_vencimientos_listado.jrxml");   
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db); 
$PHPJasperXML->outpage("I");
```

?>

Comment: Necesitas aportar más datos a tu pregunta. Así como el código implicado, así tal cual está es imposible adivinar que esta pasando para ayudarte.

Comment: Estimado @Xerif, he procedido a aclarar la pregunta, espero recibir colaboración de la comunidad....